# Great Korean Learning Textbooks: i.e TTMIK

Tags: spoken-korean, listening

So I'm looking for a good textbook that will have auditory and comprehensive applications. I tried the Integrated Korean, but I did not feel like it helped me with speaking Korean proficiently as well as how to listen. If anything, I can just read Korean well. I was wondering if Talk to Me in Korean is a good resource? I understand that they have a textbook and an online portion. They also have podcasts to help with listening and speech. I want to learn not only textbook Korean but also how how Koreans actually talk on a day-to-day basis. If anyone has used TTMIK as a primary resource for learning Korean, before I decide to pay money, how well did it help with your language proficiency skills? Would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [howToStudyKorean.com](https://howtostudykorean.com) as a very grammar focused resource which is made for native English speakers and I find it very easy to follow. It is completely free and they have a lot of example sentences for every grammar principle that they introduce and audio recordings for how these sentences are spoken.

I unfortunately do not have any experience with TTMIK.

Additionally I also use a book called "Korean Grammar in Use" which has a version for TOPIK 1 & 2 as well as TOPIK 3 & 4 and I find it very useful as a grammar reference as the table of contents is sorted by grammar principles and everything is very well explained, including natural ways of how something might be used in everyday language. I have used it multiple times to find out about a grammar principle that I found in some Korean sentence and wanted to know more about. It also comes with a CD but I have not yet bothered to listen to that. [Here's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8959951986) an amazon link for reference.

While this might not answer all your question, I hope that it helps you find good resources to use.